# SQL SERVER 2014_ difference between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

TABLE A - athletes who visited a hospital for a sprain
TABLE B - athletes who had a follow up/follow ups visit/visits at home for the sprain

The DATASET is much larger, just gave a snippet as an example

How do I in SQL SERVER....

1. IF there was a follow up in days < 7, assign a value of 1 to a col named: COL_IND, else 0
2. List the DATE of the first followup, else leave blank, put into a col named follow_up
3. Days between hospital visit and first follow up at home, if there was no follow up leave blank, place into new COL named DAYS_TO_FOLLOW

I HAVE ALREADY:

1. SEPEARTED the values in SQL based on visit
2. I have code that has separated the date into year, month and day

Where i'm stuck
3. I don't know whether to do a join of the two tables because i need to have the names match up. Was also considering an IFF statement but i don't know how i would get the names to match up.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT (float,#test1.["DATE"]) - CONVERT(float,#test2.["DATE"]) AS DIFF
FROM #test1
JOIN #test2 ON #test1.["NAME"] = #test2.["NAME"]
```

Comment: I hope you have something better than name to join on. How do you handle situations where two people have the same name? To answer the problem at hand I think you need to read up about joins. This sounds a lot like a basic left join to me. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: OK so you will join on PatientID. This still sounds like a basic left join. See the article I linked.

Comment: I used names as an example, in the dataset I was given, each name is given a unique patient ID. I used the unique ID's to join in my actual code, but i changed it on here to match my example. A basic left join sounds reasonable, as it would give a NULL to values without a follow up date, NULL would indicate 0. My only follow up then is how i would i go about converting to days. For example, i have broken down date into [2014]-[09]-[05] which each value having its own variable. 
in a case of [2014]-[10]-[05] - [2014]-[09]-[04] = 1 month, 1 day, how would i convert that just to days?

Comment: I really do appreciate the help btw :), most of my coding experience of SQL came with the use of Rstudio, and i'm trying to make the change over to SQL Studio.

Comment: You would use DATEADD. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Inner query identifies the first visit for each person, then joins that to the persons hospital visit.

```
USE tempdb;
CREATE TABLE dbo.HospitalVisit (Name VARCHAR(10), Code1 INT, VisitDate DATE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.FollowUpVisit (Name VARCHAR(10), Code1 INT, VisitDate DATE);

INSERT INTO dbo.HospitalVisit
        ( Name ,
          Code1 ,
          VisitDate
        )
VALUES  ('Chris',85,'20140905'),
('Bob',85,'20140905'),
('Angel',85,'20140905'),
('Tyler',85,'20140905'),
('Rick',85,'20140905');
INSERT INTO dbo.FollowUpVisit
        ( Name ,
          Code1 ,
          VisitDate
        )
VALUES  ('Chris',83,'20140915'),
('Chris',83,'20141015'),
('Chris',83,'20141018'),
('Bob',83,'20140910'),
('Angel',83,'20141006');


SELECT  hv.Name,
        HospitalVisitDate = hv.VisitDate,
        Flag = CASE
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, hv.VisitDate, FUV.FirstVisit) < 7 THEN
                   1
                 ELSE
                   0
               END,
        FUV.FirstVisit,
        DaystoFirstVisit = DATEDIFF(DAY, hv.VisitDate, FUV.FirstVisit)
FROM    dbo.HospitalVisit AS hv
  LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT    FUV.Name,
                    FirstVisit = MIN(FUV.VisitDate)
          FROM  dbo.FollowUpVisit AS FUV
          GROUP BY FUV.Name
        ) AS FUV
    ON hv.Name = FUV.Name;
```

However, you could probably streamline your design by putting all your visits in one table and using an additional column to indicate the visit type.

Code after new requirements provided:

```
USE tempdb;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..HospitalVisit') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.HospitalVisit;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..FollowUpVisit') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.FollowUpVisit;
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.HospitalVisit (Name VARCHAR(10),Code1 INT,VisitDate DATE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.FollowUpVisit (Name VARCHAR(10),Code1 INT,VisitDate DATE);

INSERT INTO dbo.HospitalVisit ( Name,Code1,VisitDate)
    VALUES ('Chris', 85, '20140905'),
    ('Bob', 85, '20140905'),
    ('Bob', 85, '20141005'),
    ('Angel', 85, '20140905'),
    ('Tyler', 85, '20140905'),
    ('Rick', 85, '20140905');
INSERT INTO dbo.FollowUpVisit ( Name,Code1,VisitDate)
    VALUES ('Chris', 83, '20140915'),
    ('Chris', 83, '20141015'),
    ('Chris', 83, '20141018'),
    ('Bob', 83, '20140920'),
    ('Bob', 83, '20140910'),
    ('Bob', 83, '20141010'),
    ('Bob', 83, '20141020'),
    ('Angel', 83, '20140901'),
    ('Tyler', 85, '20140904'),
    ('Angel', 83, '20141006');

WITH cte
AS (SELECT  hv.Name,
            HospitalCode = hv.Code1,
            HospitalVisit = hv.VisitDate,
            FUCode = fuv.Code1,
            FirstFollowUpVisit = fuv.VisitDate,
            FUSeq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hv.Name, hv.VisitDate ORDER BY fuv.VisitDate),
            DaystoFirstFollowUp = DATEDIFF(DAY,hv.VisitDate, fuv.VisitDate)
    FROM    dbo.HospitalVisit AS hv
      LEFT JOIN dbo.FollowUpVisit AS fuv
        ON hv.Name = fuv.Name
           AND  hv.VisitDate <= fuv.VisitDate
   )
SELECT  cte.Name ,
        cte.HospitalCode ,
        cte.HospitalVisit ,
        cte.FUCode ,
        cte.FirstFollowUpVisit ,
        cte.DaystoFirstFollowUp
FROM    cte
WHERE   cte.FUSeq = 1;
```

I added some new sample data.
Bob had two hospital visits and three new follow up visits.

Angel had a follow up visit before the hospital visit as well as after.

Tyler had a follow up visit prior to the hospital visit:

Results:

```
Name    HospitalCode    HospitalVisit   FUCode  FirstFollowUpVisit  DaystoFirstFollowUp
Angel   85  2014-09-05  83  2014-10-06  31
Bob 85  2014-09-05  83  2014-09-10  5
Bob 85  2014-10-05  83  2014-10-10  5
Chris   85  2014-09-05  83  2014-09-15  10
Rick    85  2014-09-05  NULL    NULL    NULL
Tyler   85  2014-09-05  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Note: since visit time is not included, a FU visit on the same day as a Hospital visit is counted as occurring after the Hospital visit.  You can change the visit condition from AND  hv.VisitDate <= fuv.VisitDate to AND  hv.VisitDate < fuv.VisitDate if that is not correct.

Comment: Woah this code is exactly what i'm looking for. One problem. I'm supposed to be looking at followups that come after a visit. Sometimes, you have a (visit at home) and then a visit to the hospital, and then a visit at home. which is causing me to have negative values in my datediff.